# Variable for the number of cases SPSS

Tags: spss

In my SPSS Syntax Script I compute a bunch of formulas for each cases.

Let' say this is my data:

```
id    value
 1      34
 2      12
 3      94
```

I now compute a new variable where I need the number of cases in the file (number of ids)
So

```
COMPUTE newvar = value/ NUMBER OF CASES
```

in this example NUMBER OF CASES would be 3.

Is there a command for this? thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `AGGREGATE` command without a break variable to return the number of cases in the dataset. Example below:

```
DATA LIST FREE / ID Value.
BEGIN DATA
1 34
2 12
3 94
END DATA.

AGGREGATE OUTFILE=* MODE=ADDVARIABLES
  /BREAK
  /NumberOfCases=N.

COMPUTE NewVar = Value/NumberOfCases.
```